# CakePHP Search Plugin, search for a value equal or higher than the given in the search

Tags: search, cakephp, plugins

I'm using the CakePHP Search Plugin, and there's something I can't get to work. I would like to have a search field (let's call it **age**) where a user can input a value (like 24, for example) and get as a result all the elements with a value in the **age** field of the table who have age 24 or higher. How can I do that?

So far I can perform *normal* searches, like by name or by an exact value (if you want age 24 **exactly** then it works fine).

Here's the code related with the Search Plugin that I have so far:

**- model:**

```
class Person extends AppModel{ 

    var $name = 'Person';
    public $actsAs = array('Searchable');

    public $filterArgs = array(
        array('name' => 'name', 'type' => 'like'),
        array('name' => 'age', 'type' => 'value'),
    );
}
```

**- controller:**

```
class PersonsController extends AppController {

var $name = 'Persons';
var $components = array('Search.Prg'); 
public $presetVars = array(
    array('field' => 'name', 'type' => 'value'),
    array('field' => 'age', 'type' => 'value'),
    );

function index() {
    $this->set('persons', $this->Person->find('all'));
}

/* ---------------- SEARCH PLUGIN --------------*/

public function find() {

    $this->Prg->commonProcess();
    $this->paginate['conditions'] = this->Game->parseCriteria($this->passedArgs);
    $this->set('persons', $this->paginate());
}   
}
```

**- find.ctp:**

```
//apart from the code below, I have all the code to show the results
    echo $form->create('Game', array(
        'url' => array_merge(array('action' => 'find'), $this->params['pass'])
        ));
    echo $form->input('name', array('div' => false));
    echo $form->input('age', array('div' => false));
    echo $form->submit(__('Search', true), array('div' => false));
    echo $form->end();
```

**To sum up:** with the code above, I can perfomr a search of an exact value for the **age** field. How do I change that to perform a search of 'age >= *value entered*'?

THank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is how I solved it (or at least it seems to work with all the test I've done so far):

- Changed the 'age' line by the following line in the **filterArgs** array in the model:

  ```
  array('name' => 'age', 'type' => 'query', 'method' => 'findByAge', 'field' => 'Person.age'),
  ```
- Added the following method in the same model:

  ```
  public function findByAge($data = array()) {

      $query = array(
                     'Person.age >='  => $data['age'],
                      );
      return $query;
  }
  ```

That's it! With the 'query' type, any complex query can be added to the main query using a method. Thanks to satyrwilder for pointing in the right direction!

Comment: O_o YW :) Now, don't get me wrong, I love a nifty little abstraction as much as the next dev. Maybe I'm missing something. Why didn't you just use Cake's magic findBy? No need to explicitly define findByWhatever('field') - just call it. Cake's Model class rolls a dynamic method when you roll findByWhatever, takes 'whatever', looks inside Model for field, and returns a first. (Betcha you can't guess what's different about findAllByWhatever... ^_^) Do findBy() / findAllBy() not support equal-or-greater-than comparison?

Answer (score 0):

From your presetVars -

```
array('field' => 'age', 'type' => 'value'),
```

-- filters down to your find() method from your commonProcess() method, which I presume constructs a generalized find like conditions=>array($key=>$val)?

Cake sees array key=>val pair assignments as an indication to generate a "WHERE $key=$val" condition.

To do a fuzzier pull, wherever you construct that generic find() - add a method or something just to roll those two into

```
'conditions'=>array("name LIKE '%{$name}%'", "{$age}>={$val}")
```

or whatever you've got going on.  String the arguments together for the desired effect on your query and I'm sure you can extrapolate further ways to abstract that query, if needed.

If you need a more complex solution, *Cake provides elegant built-in, extremely powerful subquery generation.* It seems like you're working awfully hard to achieve a lot of built-in functionality, but then again I don't know how complicated your situation is.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1030/Complex-Find-Conditions

HTH

Comment: Thanks satyrwilder, I'll check that out!

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered but there is another method that may be more suitable to this situation.

From the documentation

> 'expression' type: useful if you want to add condition that will generate by some method, and condition field contain several parameter like in previos sample used for 'range'. Field here contains 'Article.views BETWEEN ? AND ?' and Article::makeRangeCondition returns array of two values.

[Full Article Here](http://cakedc.com/downloads/view/cakephp_search_plugin)

I had to accomplish the same thing you did but with 5 different fields. I did not want to have to write a query for each one. Here is how I accomplished the same thing with the expression type. This is in the filterArgs array.

```
array(
    'name'=>'bathrooms', 
    'type'=>'expression', 
    'method'=>'returnNumber', 
    'field'=>'House.bathrooms >= ?'
)
```

Then I created this function in the model that simply returns the number the user submitted. When called, returnNumber will be passed two arrays.

Looks something like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [bathrooms] => 6
            [bedrooms] => 5
            [acres] => 12
            [city] => Greenville
            [year] => 2009
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => bathrooms
            [type] => expression
            [method] => returnNumber
            [field] => House.bathrooms >= ?
        )

)
```

Now for the actual function. You can use the debug statement to see what you are actually passing the function.

```
function returnNumber($arg, $name){
    // debug(func_get_args());
    // exit;
    return $arg[$name['name']];
}
```